# Why is fetch not working on my mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

I made the simplest server in NodeJS, which stocks strings in a database when requested `"/add"` and sends to my front (ReactJS) all of those strings `"/getall"`. I display them using the `map` function. Everything works as expected. But, my information is displayed only on Desktop browser, not on mobile browser (Safari or Chrome).

**Web**

[image]

**Mobile**

[image]

```
async fetchFromDatabase(){
   let url = "http://localhost:8080/getall"
   let c = 0
   await fetch(url).then((response) => {
       response.json().then((data) => {
           let values = []
           for (let i in data) {
             values.push(data[i].post)
             c++;
           }
           this.setState({
               posts: values
           })
       });
   });
 }
```

To fill in my array, I do this:

```
let allPosts = this.state.posts.map(item => (
  <div key={item} className="center-div">
    <p className="box">
      {item}
    </p>
  </div>
))
```

To render the information, I do this:

```
<div>
  {allQuestions}
</div>
```

Fetch is definitely not working for mobile. Has anyone experienced something like this?

Comment: I own an iPhone X. I have tried it with Safari, and I just downloaded Chrome for iPhone, so I guess it's the newest version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you open this page on your computer, the `http://localhost:8080` url in `fetchFromDatabase` will connect to the local webserver on your computer, and it will work. But when you open the same page on your mobile device, the same code with `localhost` in the url will try to connect to your mobile device's local web server, which is probably not existing.

Try to replacing `localhost` with [your computers local IP address](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20find%20my%20computer%27s%20local%20ip%20address), and if you are connected to the same network with your mobile phone, it should work.

Also, as @JonasWilms suggested, you can replace the full URL with `"/getAll"`, so `fetch` will send the request to the host in the base url.

Comment: I'd just use `"/getAll"` though.

Comment: It works, I don't know how I didn't think about this before

Comment: I use an absolute url (https://dummyjson.com/products) but the problem is not solved. Whats wrong with it?